# How can I get the min/max value of a sub-array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, max, min

So I have a situation where I'm tagging documents using an array, such as:

```
tags: [
   'Housing' : 10,
   'Retail'  : 1,
   'Stocks'  : 25,
]
```

I was just saving the tags themselves, but have recently added the numbers because I need to know rank/position. So the number next to the tag stands for the rank of the document in the set of documents marked with that tag.

It gets tricky in a few places, but right now I'm just trying to figure out how I add another document with one or more of these tags.  Let's say I create a new doc and tag it as Housing. Its rank needs to be set to 11, but how do I know that?

The only solution I've been able to find so far is to do a map/reduce to go through the records and find the max value for that tag, add one and save. Now, most records will probably only have 2-3 tags each, but it's theoretically possible to have 10-15.  Either way it seems like map/reduce would take a herculean effort once there are a lot of tags and a lot of records...

Is there an easier way or should I just start looking for another solution to this problem?

**Edit:**

Let me give you a little more detail about the problem I'm trying to solve... I'm displaying images in a slideshow/carousel.  The slideshow covers different categories, so using the category/tags from above, you can either view ALL of the images, or just those from Housing, Retail, Stocks, etc.  Right now I only have a handful of defined categories, but it's quite possible that these will expand over time.  They need to be filtered by the tag, and sorted by date (newest first).

Now, up until this point I've been doing just that.  The problem comes in when I want to select an arbitrary image in the middle of the deck.  Say you want to load "housing_chart.gif" that was uploaded 6 months ago.  I don't want to load 6 months of images in order to get to that image (which is basically what I'm doing now).  Instead I want to load that particular image and then be able to paginate it for next/previous images.

But in order to "paginate" the images on the carousel, I have to know the location of that image in the results... without actually getting all of the results and counting. So I figured putting a rank on them would be the way to go, but that causes other problems as well.  I don't really like the idea of creating another collection just to store ranks, but that may be the most efficient way of going about it.

Answer (score 2):

What do you need the rank for? Is this ever updated? If not and if the rank is always increasing, can't you just sort the documents for a particular tag by their date?

I would argue that information about the rank really belongs to the "tag" rather than the document, ie. each tag should have an associated list of documents with this tag - the position in that list can then define the list.

Comment: yes, and with this tag-document you easily find the rank number. And if you really need to denormalize and have the tag and rank number within the "main document" too, you add it just as that, no big searches.

Comment: Got all chatty and added some more background on the problem I'm trying to solve here to the question above.  Thanks!